# System.FormatException: Element 'HoleId' does not match any field or property of class build.Models.Product

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am new to C#. I am trying to connect COSMOS DB in C# using MongoAPI web driver. I am following their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/create-mongodb-dotnet) and trying to get data from my collection.

In the documentation, they gave sample [Templates/APIForMongoDBQuickstart-WebAPI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-templates)

Initially, by their sample data collection, I uploaded this document into my collection and I am able to run the get Products from getting Product API.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a8420fe05b73300a7cae4"),
    "CategoryName" : "Components, Saddles",
    "Sku" : "SE-R581",
    "Name" : "LL Road Seat/Saddle",
    "Description" : "The product called \"LL Road Seat/Saddle\"",
    "Price" : 27.12
}
```

When I try to add a new ObjectId field in the same document, I am getting the following error.
New Field: `"HoleId" : ObjectId("51e0373c6f35bd826f47e9a5"),`

```
System.FormatException: Element 'HoleId' does not match any field or property of class build.Models.Product.
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CursorBatchDeserializationHelper.DeserializeBatch[TDocument](RawBsonArray batch, IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings)
```

As per some forum guidelines, I done following changes in `azure-cosmos-dotnet-templates/Templates/APIForMongoDBQuickstart-WebAPI/Models/Product.cs`

```
namespace APIForMongoDBQuickstart_WebAPI.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string HoleId { get; set; } // My modified code here

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Even though I modified the code, Still I am getting the same error. Could anyone tell me where I got stuck? How can I rectify the bug?

Comment: you added HoleId to existing data?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Yes.. After updating the data, 
```{
 "_id" : ObjectId("611a8420fe05b73300a7cae4"),
 "HoleId": ObjectId("51e0373c6f35bd826f47e9a5"),
 "CategoryName" : "Components, Saddles",
 "Sku" : "SE-R581",
 "Name" : "LL Road Seat/Saddle",
 "Description" : "The product called \"LL Road Seat/Saddle\"",
 "Price" : 27.12
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like generic issue, not related to the template. Ok the actual issue if you notice on the consolse,

> MongoDB.Bson.DuplicateBsonMemberMapAttributeException: Attributes of
> type MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonIdAttribute can only be
> applied to a single member.

which means you can get rid of that error by having **`(BsonType.ObjectId)`**, should work

```
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
 public string HoleId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Still, I am getting the same error. After editing the code, I have built and run it.
`dotnet build`
 ` dotnet run` 
and I am getting the same error again

Comment: That's very strange, can you clean and try

Comment: Thank you @Sajeetharan. It worked after cleaning up.